# Webcam using Javascript and Servlet backend

Tags: javascript, mysql, servlets

Its really good to see that someone has converted JpegCam( project to integrate webcam in a web page http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/ ) php code into java http://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/capture-picture-on-webpage-with-java-backend/ .

I am also building an application in which i have to use web cam on CLIENT SIDE and store the images in DATABASE on SERVER SIDE.. My problem is that how can i refer to the image being clicked since the URL we get after capturing the image is for the server side and i cannot access that image on the server through that URL.
How can i access image in database entry page?
I know its not a good practice to store images in a database but i really don't know how to avoid it.

Please Help..!

Thanks!

Comment: Fun fact: (unrelated) You can actually use the webcam by pure JavaScript without any Flash or Java http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Hzumh/ It is currently supported by [Opera and Webkit](http://caniuse.com/stream).